# sharepoint branding : page width size due to _spBodyOnLoadWrapper() function

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2010, sharepoint-branding

i'm trying to make up a different look and feel on my sharepoint site. I try to make my main content's width down to 960px under my form tag in sharepoitn designer. when I refresh the page at the first it renders the main content down to 960px but when the page fishished loading the main content stretches itself to the whole screen's width.

I found out that it's because of the onload script running in body tag. but I caanot remove this script because this work has side effects on page functionality.

the function is _spBodyOnLoadWrapper().

does anyone know this function ? or does anyone know how to come up with this problem ?

UPDATE #1:

My css code is as follows.. I added this class to the main Form on master page:

```
.mainContent
{
width: 960px;
height:100% !important;
min-height:100% !important;
padding-top: 10px;
margin-left: auto;
margin-right: auto;
direction:rtl;
}
```

UPDATE #2:

I use v4.master template.
I have taken the ribbon out of the form tag. it's directly after body tag. because I wanted the ribbon to be streched at the top. but when i add this line of code

```
<body onload="if (typeof(_spBodyOnLoadWrapper) != 'undefined') _spBodyOnLoadWrapper();">
```

the mainContent blows up. something at the header streches in the whole width and some panels at bottom remains 960px.

Comment: how are you setting the width. Can you provide the CSS code?

Comment: I have updated my post and provided css code . thx

Comment: can you specify which type of template are you using? This will tell me what master page you're using as a template and how are you applying the .mainContent class as the standard publishing master page (nightandday.master) does not use that class.  The standard is to use #s4-bodyContainer to apply wrapper panel width

Answer (score 1):

you got me interested so I recreated your issue.  By default, the javascript will try to inline the width based on its calculations.
However, what you need is to set the class s4-notsetwidth on a wrapping container.
Here is what i did to fix your issue
Add this to the head

```
<style type="text/css">
#s4-bodyContainer {
    width: 960px;
    height:100% !important;
    min-height:100% !important;
    padding-top: 10px;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
}
/* Aligns the Top Bars */
.ms-cui-ribbonTopBars {
width: 960px!important;
margin-left:auto;
margin-right:auto;
}

/* Turns off the border on the bottom of the tabs */
.ms-cui-ribbonTopBars > div {
border-bottom:1px solid transparent !important;
}
</style>
```

Then locate the s4-workspace (that's the immediate parent of #s4-bodyContainer and add class s4-nosetwidth.  That should work for you.
Use these two references to achieve exactly what you want (not sure if you want ribbon aligned or not), [Randy Drisgill post](http://blog.drisgill.com/2010/01/error-in-current-docs-for-upgrading.html) and [Tom Wilson's post](http://styledpoint.com/blog/fixed-width-centered-aligned-sharepoint-2010-site-updated/).

Comment: thanks for your contribution I will work on your solution and let you know if it worked.

Comment: Let me know how it goes and mark the answer appropriately if it does work.